# Storing configuration related information in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am working on the Java desktop application using Swing. As the application is data centric, I am using the JDBC for connection with mySql. I would like to store database connection (connectionString), username and password in the seperate file. What will be the best approach for this?

(In .net app.config store these informations)

Comment: the property files will work fine for read and write operation

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9481515/230513) suggesting `java.util.prefs.Preferences`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the parameters in a properties file like

```
hostname=localhost:3306/mydb
username=root
password=pass
```

Store this information in a properties file like say config.properties. You can load the properties in java during runtime using the `Properties` class in java

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
String connectionString = prop.getProperty("hostname")
String username = prop.getProperty("username")
String password = prop.getProperty("password")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [properties file](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) for that. 
Hibernate has already its [properties configuration file](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional). You can also use [hibernate.cfg.xml](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig).