# Update JTable through file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable, updating

Alright so I'm reading some scores off of a text file and when the user is done playing the game, it asks you if you want to save the score or not, I only have one problem with this. It reads and writes fine to and front from the text file, it's just that the JTable isn't updating whenever a new score is added. The Object[][] is being read off a text file and I was just wondering if there was a method like "table.setData(Object[][] o);" sorta thing, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You want to add row's to the JTable's TableModel, often a DefaultTableModel object. If you need more help on this, you'll have to tell us more of the details of your code and your problem. A lot more.

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue inc. AbstractTableMolde's method `table.setData(Object[][] o)`

Comment: Alright nvm, I fixed it, all I needed was that DefaultTableModel object, there's a method called setDataVector(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames); thank you

Comment: Also consider `java.util.prefs.Preferences`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9481515/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you can accept an answer and keep your reputation up:

It sounds like you need to set a `DefaultTableModel`.

Then you can use `((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).setDataVector(yourData, columnHeaders);`. With 'yourData' being  an `Object[][]`, and 'columnHeaders' `Object[]`

That should do exactly what you need.