# Java Save and Load Program's State

Tags: java, swing, savestate

in my java Project I have several classes/java files but is in Menu class that is stored all the lists of stuff that is used. In terms of data I store 6 Lists(2 ArrayLists and 4 HashMaps) which 1 is defined in Menu class and others are in different classes.
So I need to create a *savestate* and a *loadstate* to when I close the program to restore the previous state. All the Lists are implemented with *Serializable*

Is it possible to save all the Menu's state and reload it or I've to save all the lists individually? Save all in one file would be great.

Here is the function I have, works(no warnings/errors) and compiles but doesn't creates the file "*datafiles*".

Any ideas?

```
    private void MenuSave(){
    String wd = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(wd);
    int rc = fc.showDialog(null, "Select Data File Location to Save");

    if (rc == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    String filename = file.getAbsolutePath();

    savestate(lf, lc, lv, lcl,filename);}
    }


public void savestate(Cars la, Bikes l2, Motos l3, Planes l4, People n1, Food n2, String filename){

    int i;
    File out = new File(filename);

    ObjectOutputStream output = null;

    try{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
        for(Car c : la.getCars().values()){
            output.writeObject(c);
        }
        for(Bike b : l2.getBikes().values()){
            output.writeObject(b);
        }
        for(Moto m : l3.getMotos().values()){
            output.writeObject(m);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n1.size();i++)
        {output.writeObject(n1.get(i)));
        }
        for(i=0;i<n2.size();i++)
        {output.writeObject(n2.get(i)));
        }


    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null) {
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to sprinkle your code with println statements to see what code gets called and what the state of the variables at the times of these calls.

Comment: Why not use `java.util.Preferences`?

Comment: @trashgod  `Preferences` might be the better option, though we don't know enough yet to determine for sure.  See my comment to mKorbel below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I thought I just need to save the lists individually without that *for* .
1-Choose where to save the file, then save the Classes in there.
2-To read just parse the input and store replacing the current Classes.
...

```
    String wd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(wd);

    fc.setDialogType((int)JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);


    int rc = fc.showDialog(null, "Select Data File");
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    if (rc == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

    ObjectOutputStream output = null;

    try{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    output.writeObject(list1);
    output.writeObject(list2);
    output.writeObject(list3);
    ....


    output.close();

    }catch (IOException x){
     ....
    }catch(NullPointerException n){
     ....    
    }}
```

to read is just the same:

```
    String wd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(wd);
    fc.setDialogType((int)JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
    int rc = fc.showDialog(null, "Select Data File to Load");
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    if (rc == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    String filename = file.getAbsolutePath();


    ObjectInputStream input = null;
    try{
    input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    this.list1=(ListType1)input.readObject();
    this.list2=(ListType2input.readObject();
    ....
    }catch (IOException x){
      ...  

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException x){
      ...
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> doesn't creates the file "datafiles".

I'll bet that it does, just not where you are expecting to find it.  Don't "drop your files wherever they fall", put them some place that is read/writable, logical and reproducible.

```
String filename = "datafiles";
File out = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), filename);
// ...
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out));
```

Then look in user home for the `datafiles` (why does it have no file type/extension?) file.

1. The [`File` constructor that accepts 2 `String` (parent & name) parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) uses the correct `File` separator for the OS.
2. `user.home` is a [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) that points to a stable, reproducible path that has read/write access.

Comment: Preferences, mentioned by @trashgod

Comment: @mKorbel  I thought `Preferences` was purely for values of `String` or 'simple' object types `Long`/`Float` rather than generic `Object` values as implied by `ObjectOutputStream`.  OTOH, perhaps the OP can store the attributes of each object as those basic types. More input is required from OP - definitions for the classes would be very helpful.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I like `user.home`, but `Preferences` can store complex types; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9481515/230513).

Comment: With that it creates indeed the file in user folder with 4bytes. But there is a problem, It only creates if all the lists are empty, if I add an element to a list it gives an exception _NullPointerException_ . Then I'll need to handle the load...