# Saves game level settings

Tags: java, file, save, settings

I have been coding for about a month and I have found ways to adapt around ever problem but one. The problem as you can probably see by the title is how to make a way to make game saves. I am currently creating a very simple game that has about 5 classes of my code and maybe 2 of Java Swing GUI.

I know how I would like to go about the saving process but I have no idea how to do it in my code. How I would like to go about doing this is by making the code print a Number or Integer to a file to represent a Level. For example if you completed level 1 the number in the file would be 1. I have tried some templates for this but none of them work.

I understand how to write to a file but my problem is reading it from a jar or even creating a file then reading it from a place on the computer. I need to know how to find a file URL for different computers because some use Docs and Settings and other Users. Please could someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the jar is read only, it can only contain the 'default settings'.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052359/418556) for the general strategy to deal with such a [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).

Speaking of which (embedded resources) see the [info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for more details on how to access them.

Here is an example of [storing and reading a `Properties` file from the 'current directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778332/418556).

As mentioned by @MadProgrammer though, it is safest to put the settings file into a (*sub-directory*) of `user.home`, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771948/418556).

---

But a properties file is just one option.  You might also serialize an object, or write the file in a custom format that your app. knows how to read, for the first two off the top of my head.

Besides 'serialize (in some form) in a `File`', there is also the [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API, or for desktop applications launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), the `PersistenceService`.  Here is a [demo. of the service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know how to find a file url for different computers because
>   some use Docs and Settings and other Users

The `System` property `user.home` points to the user's home directory

```
File userHome = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP can use the `java.lang.prefs` package too, as that's OS independent.

Comment: MadProgrammer Could you please explane a little more

Comment: @EricJablow Or `Properties`, but the OP did state they know how to write a file...

Comment: @Dev I'm not sure what else you want to know.  You said you know how to write a file and you wanted some way to get the users "home" folder (ie Docs and Settings under Windows), `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/` will give you a reference to the user's home directory.  If you're on Windows, I suggest using `AppData/Roaming/{your application name}` to place files in...

Comment: Ok Thanks now I under stand most but if I write a file in AppData/Roaming/{your application name} It will look past anything before that in the URL like to C:/Documents and Setting/{User}/?

Comment: Basically, you need to prefix any path you want to use with `System.getProperty("user.home")`.  For example `File userHome = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "AppData/Roaming/{your application name}");`, will give you a `File` reference to the user's home directory plus the destination path...