# How do you load values into a JTable so that it shows the previous values when the form is opened?

Tags: java, arrays, forms, netbeans, jtable

How do you load array values into a `JTable` such that whenever the form is opened, it shows the previous values of the table? I do not want to connect the form to any databases.

This is my code so far, it allows me to enter texts to the text field, and when I click "create customer" button, it stores the value into the `JTable`. However if I exit and reopen the form, the data previously in the table disappears. And i have done some research, but it seems like connecting netbeans to a database is the only way to save and retrieve data. However, I believe that storing data into the array is possible too, but Ii do not know how to bring out the value in the array into the table.

I need some help. It is for my school project.
FYI, some of the notations I've used: `rbtn = radiobutton, tb = textfields, lbl = label`

```
public class Customer extends javax.swing.JFrame {
String gender;
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

int m=10; //array memory size

String[] name = new String[m];
String[] age = new String[m];
String[] genderm = new String [m];
String[] id = new String [m];
String[] mobile = new String [m];
String[] email = new String [m];
String[] address = new String [m];
String[] date = new String [m];
String[] photo = new String[m];

public Customer() {
    initComponents();
    tbdate.setText(day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
    lblphoto.setIcon(null);              
}     

private void btncreateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent  evt)      {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (rbtnmale.isSelected()){
        gender = "Male";
    }
    else if (rbtnfemale.isSelected()){
        gender = "Female";
    }
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jtablecustinfo.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{tbname.getText(),tbage.getText(),gender,tbid.getText(),tbmobile.getText(),tbemail.getText(),tbaddress.getText(),tbdate.getText(),lblphoto.getIcon()});

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
    name[i]=tbname.getText();
    age[i] = tbage.getText();
    genderm[i]=gender;
    id[i]=tbid.getText();
    mobile[i]=tbmobile.getText();
    email[i]=tbemail.getText();
    address[i]=tbaddress.getText();
    date[i]=tbdate.getText();
    photo[i]= tbimage.getText();;
    }

    //Reset everything after creation
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successfully Created Customer");
    tbname.setText("");
    tbage.setText("");
    tbid.setText("");
    tbmobile.setText("");
    tbemail.setText("");
    tbaddress.setText("");
    tbdate.setText("");
    rbtnmale.setSelected(false);
    rbtnfemale.setSelected(false);
    tbdate.setText(day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
    gender = "";
    tbimage.setText("");
    lblphoto.setText("          -Import photo-");
    lblphoto.setIcon(null);
}
```

I have included the main points of my code, hope it is sufficient to view!

Comment: For small amounts of data, consider `java.util.prefs.Preferences`.

Comment: @trashgod ahh, would you be able to provide me with some examples on how to use it? Sorry, i hadn't come across this function in class, Ive done some research and i only know that it can save user preferences, but how?

Comment: I've elaborated below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For small amounts of data, consider [`java.util.prefs.Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).

> Would you be able to provide me with some examples on how to use it?

Several examples are examined in the [*Preferences API Overview*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html) and the example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481515/230513) ([API](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/org/gcs/robot/RCPrefs.html) and [code](https://sourceforge.net/p/robotchase/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/org/gcs/robot/RCPrefs.java)). Alternatively, consider `javax.jnlp.PersistenceService`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6886694/230513), "for applications that are running in the restricted execution environment."

This minimal example updates a single cell by adding the previously saved value to the table and overriding the table model's `setValueAt()` implementation to save any change. Edit the table, quit and restart to see the effect.

[image]

```
package org.name.table;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34616583/230513
 */
public class TablePreference {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TablePreference");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(new PrefModel()) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(128, 32);
            }
        }));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class PrefModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        private static final int DEFAULT = 42;
        private static final String VALUE_NAME = "value";
        private final Preferences p = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TablePreference.class);

        public PrefModel() {
            addColumn("A");
            addRow(new Object[]{p.getInt(VALUE_NAME, DEFAULT)});
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
            super.setValueAt(aValue, row, col);
            p.putInt(VALUE_NAME, (int) aValue);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new TablePreference()::display);
    }
}
```